# How to deploy a keycloak's SPI project using the Keycloak Deployer (/deploy)?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

In [Keycloak's documentation](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.2/server_development/topics/providers.html), it's stated that in order to deploy the provider, I can

> copy your provider jar to the Keycloak deploy/ directory, your
>   provider will automatically be deployed.

I'm indeed searching for a simple copy-paste way to deploy a provider without CLI nor through maven.

The problem is that I can't find any `/deploy` folder in keycloak's server :(

Below is the result for searching files/folders with the word deploy.

**Any idea how to simply deploy the an SPI project into Keycloak?** Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Mailing list: http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2017-October/011941.html

Answer (score 6):

Create a subdirectory "providers" in  keycloak home directory,
then copy your JAR files to this subdirectory,
then restart the keycloak server.

Answer (score 3):

In the newer version of keycloak you have to put your custom SPI into the `/deployments` folder. This is how I did in `Keycloak 4.6.0.Final`

Comment: If it's a standalone setup, this applies. According to README found in that folder. If you don't have this folder, you aren't running standalone.

Comment: create `deployments` directory under `domain` folder of your installation if you are running in domain mode. Place the jar under this `domain/deployments` directory

Comment: @AmitP  not working, no automatic deployments when creating such a folder in domain mode